# How do you exclude global types declared in TypeScript definitions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native

Many libraries are written for both the web, Node servers, and mobile apps like React Native. as a result they can be included either via `<script />` tags, calls to `require()`, or using the modern `import` keywords, especially if you're using tools like Webpack or frameworks like React Native.

Their TypeScript dependencies therefore will often expose types not only using the `export` keyword, but also in a global namespace. This allows code that uses TypeScript on the browser and includes libraries perhaps from CDNs using `<script />` tags to make use of types that will be globally available in those environments.

For example, `jquery`, `big.js`, and many more libraries use this pattern.

When you're coding modern JavaScript but using a library that exposes global types for the browser case, how do you exclude those types from entering the global namespace in environments like Node and React Native where they are actually not available?

Answer (score 4):

When compiling your TypeScript code, assuming that you've installed typing using something like `npm install @types/node @types/jest`, [use the `types` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) to specify which type declarations get included globally. For example, in `tsconfig.json`, include code like this:

```
{
  compilerOptions: {
    // ...
    // @types/node and @types/jest will be included globally.
    types: ["node", "jest"],
    // ...
  }
}
```

This way, TypeScript will only include the declarations for those specified libraries automatically, including the global ones. The rest of the types still work when you import—TypeScript will resolve those libraries when it sees you `import` them—but this way, only the libraries you specify that provide global types for your environment will be made available, allowing the TypeScript compiler to inform you of missing imports more reliably.

Thanks to Github @googol [for the tip on DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/29304#issuecomment-425841872).

Comment: This isn't working for me. At least with big.js. No matter what values types has, Big is included globally.

Comment: hmmm yeah I actually ran into this too now and I'm left confused. It's def working for `jest` when I remove/add it but I'm running into Big acting up now.

Comment: Is there an easy way to include all explicitly installed `@types` packages while excluding the browser lib types still?